# What are best practices to run command on all nodes in a HDP cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

Often in a hadoop environment, you are required to run a command or a script or copy a file to all nodes in the cluster.

What are efficient ways of doing that (without having to ssh to each node separately)?

Example:
[When upgrading Ambari, you are required to run many commands on all nodes where a certain component is installed - e.g. Infra, SmartSense, etc.](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.0.3/bk_ambari-upgrade/content/upgrade_ambari_infra.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use Ansible to do that. It will do the job for you.

But you can use puppet or Salt or Chef.